# How to Replace IP at Specific Line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file (`.htaccess`) which contains below excerpt.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 45.152.35.2
</Files>
```

I need to replace `45.152.35.2` with my current IP. But `45.152.35.2` is not static. I need to find the IP expression at `allow from` line and replace it with my current IP.

I also need to get my current IP (`75.152.35.4`) from `w` command:

```
12:13:07 up 21 days,  3:01,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.13, 0.12
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    75.152.35.4      14:29    0.00s  0.10s  0.00s w
```

How can I get current IP from `w` command and replace `allow from` line in `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed -i "s/allow from [0-9,\.]*/allow from $(w -h | awk '{print $3}' | head -1)/g" .htaccess
```

**Explanation:**

- `sed -i "s/.../$(...)/g .htaccess`: replaces the `allow from` line with
- `w -h | awk '{print $3}' | head -1`: the frist line of the output of `w`

Comment: I saw which is why I deleted my comment and instead upvoted :). You could also use `sed -i -r "s/(allow from )[0-9\.]*/\1 $(w | awk '($NF=="w"){print $3}')/" .htaccess` which has the added benefit of ensuring the right IP even if `w` returns multiple lines and multiple users.

Comment: @chaos works great but I want to change `allow from` line only for `wp-login.php` section. `.htaccess` file may contain many `allow from` lines. Your code replaces globally. How can it be done to change `allow from` line in `wp-login.php` section only?